# Why this call to isnan is NOT ambiguous? a.k.a. keyword using introducing 2 times similar function declarations

Tags: c++, namespaces

The following code compiles and generates a call to `std::isnan`, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94dd724e1fdf5a57)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

namespace foo {
    template<class T> 
    inline bool isnan (T x)
    { //Fake function returning always true
       std::cout << "foo::isnan" << std::endl;
       return true;
    }
}

using foo::isnan;
using std::isnan;

int main () {
    std::cout << isnan(5.5f) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Why isn't that function call ambiguous?**

Looking at cmath.h, I see:

```
  template<typename _Tp>
    inline typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_arithmetic<_Tp>::__value,
                       int>::__type
    isnan(_Tp __f)
    {
      typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__promote<_Tp>::__type __type;
      return __builtin_isnan(__type(__f));
    }
```

which, at least to me, doesn't look as necessarily a better match.

*Motivation of this question:*

I found these lines of code (probably result of some Eclipse autogeneration)

```
using std::isnan
using boost::math::isnan
```

And I was wondering why the compiler wouldn't generate at least a warning.

Comment: For what it's worth it is ambiguous when compiling with [gcc 5.1](https://ideone.com/RQwd5J) and [gcc 4.9.2](http://cpp.sh/843wn)

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Tbh, I would personally not like my editor auto-generating stuff like that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Considering that here the `std::cout` is just for debug purpose, the inherent `std::flush` is appropriate. But yours is a good suggestion in general.

Comment: I don't see where flushing provides any benefit for this code. But if you need a stream that always gets flushed, use `std::cerr`.

Comment: @PeteBecker We are discussing about style choices, and using `std::cerr` to output something that is actually not an error is far from ideal, at least in my opinion.

Comment: @Antonio - your "here the `std::cout` is **just for debug purposes**" is a pretty good description of the role of `std::cerr` or `std::clog`. Ruling out the use of `std::cerr` to "output something that is actually not an error" is design by pun.

Comment: @PeteBecker It's a matter of opinions. We are wasting our time here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation must declare the following overloads, or behave as if those overloads are declared, when you `#include <cmath>`:

```
bool isnan( float arg );
bool isnan( double arg );
bool isnan( long double arg );
bool isnan( Integral arg );
```

The first one of those is unambigously the best match, so the compiler must choose it. (Relevant standardese is in 26.8/10 in N4141 for those who care.)

Note that the last overload<sup>†</sup> may be declared in a way that conflicts with your template, in which case the `using std::isnan;` will cause a redeclaration error. (That happens in gcc5 and earlier.) If that `using` does not cause an error though, the call is well formed.

Interestingly, clang does think the call is ambiguous. That should not happen as I explained above.

---

> And I was wondering why the compiler wouldn't generate at least a warning.

You are using the `using` feature to pull declarations into some scope, which is the intended use. So I see no reason to warn here. I would however configure my editor in such a way that is does not auto-generate `using` declarations like this, as that may have surprising results.

---

<sup>†</sup>This overload is not to be understood in the literal sense I pasted above. What exactly that overload stands for is implementation defined, it may be a set of overloads, a template, ... It behaves like casting the argument to `double` for all integral types.

Comment: Indeed, in cmath.h I see a section `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L` with `constexpr bool
  isnan(float __x)
  { return __builtin_isnan(__x); }`Anyway, although arguably wrong, clang behaviour seems preferable to me.